# How to find the center of the div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag with id container. How can I find its center using either jquery or javascript?

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

here is css

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Find the centre relative to what? The element's top-left corner, the top-left corner of the page..?

Comment: the element's top left corner.

Comment: something like: `div = $('#container'); var center = new Array( div.width() / 2 , div.height() / 2 );` :)

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. I recommend `width * 0.5` instead of `width / 2` because it is faster ;)

Comment: Note that `position()` is relative to the element's offset parent and that `offset()` is relative to the document. If you want to know where the center of a div is on the screen, use `offset()`.

Answer (score 6):

Is it this?

```
var cX = $('#container').offset().left + $('#container').width()/2;
var cY = $('#container').offset().top + $('#container').height()/2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this retrieve the center-point of the element relative to its offset parent, rather than to the top-left point of the element itself? (Which I assume is what the OP wants, from his comment to the question.)

Comment: The comment was added after the response so I just assumed

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
 var $this = $("#container");
 var offset = $this.offset();
 var width = $this.width();
 var height = $this.height();

 var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
 var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;
 console.log(centerX ,centerY)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

1. width / outerWidth
2. height / outerHeight

Answer (score -1):

jQuery way:

```
var div = $('#container');
var divCoords = { 
    x : div.width() * 0.5 , 
    y : div.height() * 0.5
};
```